# How to get TypeInfo from SemanticModel for MemberAccessExpressionSyntax from lambda expression?

Tags: c#, roslyn

For example I have the code:

```cs
using System.Linq;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string name = new Person().Name; // SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo() returns string. It's OK.
            string[] names = new Person[] { new Person() }.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray(); // SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo() returns ErrorTypeSymbol.
                     names = new Person[] { new Person() }.Select(Person p => p.Name).ToArray(); // SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo() returns string. It's OK.
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get TypeInfo for `p.Name` from lambda expression of LINQ Select extension.
I'm writing in my Roslyn analyzer:

```cs
syntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MemberAccessExpressionSyntax>().ToArray();
```

And I got:

```
[0] = {MemberAccessExpressionSyntax} new Person().Name
[1] = {MemberAccessExpressionSyntax} new Person[] { new Person() }.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray
[2] = {MemberAccessExpressionSyntax} new Person[] { new Person() }.Select
[3] = {MemberAccessExpressionSyntax} p.Name
```

Then I'm trying to get TypeInfo for the first `MemberAccessExpressionSyntax  new Person().Name`:

```cs
context.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree).GetTypeInfo(syntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MemberAccessExpressionSyntax>().ToArray()[0]).Type.Name
```

It returns `String`. It's OK.

But when I'm trying to get type of MemberAccessExpression from lambda expression `Select(p => p.Name)`:

```cs
context.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree).GetTypeInfo(syntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MemberAccessExpressionSyntax>().ToArray()[3]).Type.Name
```

It returns empty string.

How to get TypeInfo from SemanticModel for MemberAccessExpressionSyntax from lambda expression without explicit type declaration?